# Photo-Tagging from scratch in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, photo-tagging

Can anyone suggest me some good tutorials for photo tagging?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try google for tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Try here. It uses the acts-as-taggable-on gem. I haven't tried it myself, but will soon as I have a similar feature to implement.

http://swought.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/image-tagging-and-autosuggestion-with-rails-and-jquery/

The gem can be found here:
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on